# Changing URL after selecting value from dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a HTML form with two dropdown menus. First dropdown is prepopulated from database with PHP, second one is linked with first one and uses AJAX to update values according to the selection from first one.

How can I make the URL to change after selecting something from the dropdown menu? E.g. after selecting something from first dropdown, URL would be something like http://myurl.com/form.php/option1 and after second choice http://myurl.com/form.php/option1+option2.

My code:

Scripts:

```
<script>
  function kuvaRingkond(str) {
    if (str == "") {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
      return;
    }
    else {

      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
      else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
          document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getringkond.php?q="+str,true);
      xmlhttp.send();
    }
  }
</script>

  function AjaxFunction()
  {
    var httpxml;
    try
    {
      // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
      httpxml=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch (e)
    {
      // Internet Explorer
      try
      {
        httpxml=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
      }
      catch (e)
      {
        try
        {
          httpxml=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch (e)
        {
          alert("Teie brauser ei toeta Ajaxit!");
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
    function stateck() 
    {
      if(httpxml.readyState==4)
      {

        var myarray = JSON.parse(httpxml.responseText);
        // Remove the options from 2nd dropdown list 
        for(j=document.form.kandidaat.options.length-1;j>=0;j--)
        {
          document.form.kandidaat.remove(j);
        }

        var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
        optn.text = 'Vali kandidaat';
        optn.value = '0';
        document.form.kandidaat.options.add(optn);

        for (i=0;i<myarray.data.length;i++)
        {
          var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
          optn.text = myarray.data[i].Eesnimi + ' ' + myarray.data[i].Perekonnanimi;
          optn.value = myarray.data[i].KandidaadiID;
          document.form   .kandidaat.options.add(optn);

        }

      }
    }
  // end of function stateck
  var url="dd.php";
  var erakond_id=document.getElementById('s1').value;
  url=url+"?erakond_id="+erakond_id;
  url=url+"&sid="+Math.random();
  httpxml.onreadystatechange=stateck;
  //alert(url);
  httpxml.open("GET",url,true);
  httpxml.send(null);
}

  </script>
```

Form:

```
  <form role="form" name="form" method="POST" action="haaletamine_form.php">

     <div class="form-group">
       <label for="erakond">
         Erakond:
       </label>
       <?php
require "connection_pdo.php";// connection to database 
echo "<select class ='form-control' name=erakond id='s1' onchange=AjaxFunction();>";
echo "<option selecter='selected'>Vali erakond</option>"; 
$sql="select * from erakonnad "; // Query to collect data from table 
foreach ($dbo->
query($sql) as $row) {
echo "<option value=$row[ErakonnaID]>$row[ErakonnaNimi]</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="kandidaat">
          Kandidaat:
        </label>
        <select class="form-control" name=kandidaat id='s2' onchange="kuvaRingkond(this.value)">
          <option selecter="selected">
            Vali kandidaat
          </option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div id="txtHint">
        <b>
        </b>
      </div>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
        Kinnita valik
      </button>
   </form>
```

Thanks!

Comment: better show it in php fiddle

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it.

HTML

```
<select id="select-list">
    <option>Option One</option>
    <option>Option Two</option>
    <option>Option Three</option>
</select>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#select-list').on('change', function() {

        var nSelectOption = $('#select-list').find(':selected').text();

        switch(nSelectOption) {
            case "Option One":
            window.location.href = 'http://google.com';
            break;
            case "Option Two":
            window.location.href = 'http://google.com';
            break;
            case "Option Three":
            window.location.href = 'http://google.com';
            break;
        }
    });    
});
```